# ANSI Chinese Codepage Conversion (CP950)

Tags: cjk, codepages, windows-1252

I am puzzled about the meaning of the chinese `CP 950`.

AFAIK, ANSI consists of 256 characters, but `CP950` seems to have quite more.
On the WIKI page ([CP950](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_950)) a layout defined by Microsoft is shown as image with a reference to a textfile describing the translations made.
Did I get it right, that a western europe CP (e.g.: `CP1250`) is translated into `CP950` by combining multiple characters from `CP1250` into one character of `CP950`? Vice versa, a single `CP950` character gets dissolved into multiple `CP1250` characters?
Could somebody show me the translation process with the help of a simple example? (e.g.: `CP1250` A7 (**§**) is translated into `CP950` ... this way)

I do really struggle to get the process right. Summarized I did understand, that no Unicode is needed to represent the chinese characters in `CP950` (traditional), that ANSI is still applicable, and transformations from western europe to `CP950` could be applied.

Comment: Well, there's the abstract idea of a *character* like "§", and then there's the question what bytes do you use to represent it. Single-byte encodings like CP1250 just map all possible values of a byte to one character, hence they can only represent 256 different characters. Encodings like CP950 are a bit more sophisticated and use multiple bytes per character and some rules you need to follow. To translate from one encoding to another, you decode the bytes to the abstract character, and then encode it again to bytes using the rules of your target encoding…

Comment: Also see [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)…

Comment: Thanks for your link and explanation, great article. This basically means that the CP950 characters get decoded to byte representation while getting transformed to CP1250 following some rules, but with e.g. 0x77bb 0xc2a4 the single bytes get table-mapped into CP1250 representation (e.g. a4 results in ¤), thus resulting into a string having more characters. Unfortunately, no official documents do exist to do some transformation with pen and paper?

Comment: In practice all encoding conversions go via Unicode these days, since otherwise you'd need to have an *n-to-n* mapping of every encoding to every other encoding. Decode bytes in one encoding to the defined abstract Unicode character, then encode that character to your target encoding according to its rules. Those individual rules are… _somewhere…_